# como envío un cuerpo json por post usando volley?

Tags: android, json, post, android-volley

estoy usando volley para hacer peticiones http a un servidor y debo hacer el registro de usuarios, el problema es que debo enviar los datos en un solo json como se ve en la imagen, ademas de añadir el encabezado application/json, pero no se como enviarlo desde volley pues no son objetos separados sino un solo cuerpo json.

[image: Cuerpo JSON a enviar al server]

asi es como hago las peticiones enviando parametros post

```
        final JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("usuario", usuario.toString());
        data.put("paquete", pref.getDatosRegistro("paquete"));
        data.put("gustos", String.valueOf(gustos));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("data", data.toString());

    CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            progress.dismiss();
            Log.i("RESPONSE", String.valueOf(response));
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Entro al error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            String your_string_json = data.toString(); // put your json
            return your_string_json.getBytes();
        }
    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

espero puedan ayudarme

Saludos.

Comment: No pongas código como una foto (el json), impide que la gente pueda copiarlo facilmente para ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

El error que tienes es que a tu solicitud estás enviando el objeto params que es  un mapa de cadenas de texto pero lo que tu solicitud Espera es un objeto json entonces lo que debes hacer es convertir ese objeto en un json de la misma forma a como lo hiciste con Data...

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
```

Y a tu solicitud en vez de enviar params envías json